# Duplicate number generated when using python random module

Tags: python, random

I have been using Python random randint to generate five random numbers from a certain range.

I need to run thousands of this random process.

However, I found that when the code run above thousands time, it begins to generate a lot of duplicated number.

here is my code:

```
list = random.sample(range(1, 4171), 5)
```

it supposes to generate five different number every time I run it, but when I run it thousands of time, it begins to generate combination like:

```
[4171, 4171, 3624, 3843, 3921]
[4171, 4171, 3624, 3843, 3921]
[2024, 4171, 4171, 3596, 2960]
```

I don't understand why there are so many duplicated 4171 in the generated list?

Is there some kind of bug in it?

I just want the code to generate five different numbers in a certain range.

Comment: Run a statistical analysis, you can determine whether or not the random numbers are in fact random. (Which they are not, they are only pseudo-random, but besides the point)

Comment: Hm, It looks strange to have repeating element within same sample. From the docs for `random.sample`: _Used for random sampling  **without replacement**_. Also, don't use `list` as name.

Comment: You could try numpy.random.choise as an alternative.

Comment: I guess there is something different going on in your code. Reading again - first you say you use `random.randint()` and then show code with `random.sample()`. Can you show [mre].

Comment: Since you are running it 1000 times and every time you are taking 5 samples, it is guaranteed that some values will be same between 2 list since there are a total of 4170 values in original list. But in a single list, I have not found same value to occur more than once. I ran the code 10^6 times. I don't know why it is happening with you.

Comment: Thanks for your guys answer it is eventually something wrong with my code, cause I am using a little complicated algorithm outside this random process, I kind of have a general idea what went wrong, thanks!!!!!